# Is there a typeclass in haskell for boolean values?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am trying to learn some Haskell by looking at a superb short and educational article on comonad application from 2006 [link](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/12/evaluating-cellular-automata-is.html) and it contains an expression like `rule (U (a:_) b (c:_)) = not (a && b && not c || (a==b))` whre `U` is a zipper comonad. That is stated in `data U x = [x] x [x]` and accompanying implementations of the comonad operations.

Trying to learn more, I am attempting to annotate the type of the expression manually. A wise choice seems to be `rule :: U Bool -> Bool`, but that seems a bit... restrictive. I could imagine other types that would be able to have truthyness values, such as Ints (0 corresponds to false, all other values could be True) and other.

If there was a type class for truthyness called `truthy`, I guess I could write `rule :: (Truthy t) => U t -> Bool`. Since I want to iterate over `rule`, the first type annotation (`rule :: U Bool -> Bool`) is good enough, but still the question tickles my brain.

Is there such a typeclass? If there is, what is it called? If not, why is there no need for it?

Comment: I'd rather use an explicit predicate `p :: t -> Bool`, than relying on a kind-of implicit conversion. Also one can use `rule (fmap p someU)` if needed. More generally, if `if, &&, ||, ...` do not support "truthy" values, why should a library support those, especially when there's a good explicit way to convert? (And, before someone asks, I'd not extend `if,...` to a typeclass -- even Java removed the C conditional `if (intExpr)` in favor of a better, explicit, statically checked boolean expression)

Comment: Not being able to accidentally use a non-boolean value like 0 when you meant to use a boolean is exactly why we have a type system. This typeclass would do nothing but subvert the intention of the type system. One useful typeclass that is somewhat similar would be a lattice, where True and False would be top and bottom, respectively.

Comment: The answer below mentions boolean algebras; this structure can be formalized in terms of both rings and lattices, and there are several packages available which define classes for these algebraic structures. In a sense, a boolean algebra is "too big" to be practical - in most cases, you are actually working with a smaller algebraic structure (e.g. a monoid).  "...other types that would be able to have truthyness values, such as Ints" - the equivalence class of `Int` w.r.t the equality identifying 0 with 0 and every other number with every other number is a perfectly reasonable Boolean algebra!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digression: Generally we don't use type classes to do what you might call *mere overloading*, of the sort you find in dynamic languages (e.g. making `+` mean "concatenate lists" or "add ints", or overloading boolean operations to work on "truthy" values as in your question). The difference is I guess that we say good abstractions are made with type classes that have a set of laws that hold them together, so that you can write *polymorphic* code that is useful. It might be that we can make a "truthy" class that's good by this standard but I'm not sure.

But to get to your question, there are certainly classes that abstract boolean logic to some degree (the field of study here being maybe [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)), the most relevant here probably being the [`Bits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Bits.html) class from `Data.Bits`.

So you'd get:

```
-- note, the polymorphic `t` has cooties, and we'd need to be able to
-- make the caller polymorphic in a sensible way too for this to make sense
rule :: (Bits t) => U t -> t
rule (U (a:_) b (c:_)) = complement (a .&. b .&. complement c .|. complement (a `xor` b))
```

The only tricky bit above is `a == b` becomes the wordy more general form ``` complement (a ``xor`` b) ```. Actually if we restrict ourselves to the fundamental operations (AND/OR/NOT), then the more general form of `==` is quite complicated:

```
a .==. b = complement ((a .|. b) .&. complement (a .&. b))
```

It would be interesting to see whether or in what way this operation makes sense with this more general type (I don't know what it's meant to do), e.g. does it do something sensible for `Int`. Then compare that with `Int` had we used your "truthy" class. Is one more useful than the other? Does the `Bits` version give you any new insight into the algorithm or is it just an arbitrary overloading?

**Edit**: here's something interesting about working in this more abstract domain: we can use the laws of boolean algebra to reduce and understand our expression better. For instance by [handing it off to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NOT+%28%28A+and+B+and+NOT+C%29+or+%28NOT+%28A+XOR+B%29%29%29) we can observe that the normalized forms of our expression *don't contain `c` at all* (you should double-check I haven't made a mistake somewhere), so we might as well have written:

```
rule (U (a:_) b _) = (a && not b) || (not a && b)
```

This might be interesting insight (is that `c` even necessary in our data structure?) or might indicate a bug in our logic.

Comment: Actually the c is probably unnecessary.... I took it verbatim from the article referenced, so I didn't reflect on it before!  Thanks for a nice answer.